# Burger menu not hiding on menu click

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem in my burger menu. It is not hiding after I click on the menu. I'm a beginner and I don't know where the problem is?
I need your help please. If you need any other information about my code feel free to ask me.

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar default">
    <div class="container mob-logo">
        <div class="navbar-header col-sm-2 tablet-logo">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle mob-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar nature"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar nature"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar nature"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="mobile-sidebar">
                <span class="sidebar-btn btn fa-bar-hide" data-action="toggle" data-side="right" >
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right ">
            <li class="active">
                    <a href="#accueil" data-du-smooth-scroll data-du-scrollspy>Accueil</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#home" data-du-smooth-scroll data-du-scrollspy>Groupe</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Competences" data-du-smooth-scroll data-du-scrollspy>Competences</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#Services" data-du-smooth-scroll data-du-scrollspy>Services</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#References" data-du-smooth-scroll data-du-scrollspy>References</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact" data-du-smooth-scroll data-du-scrollspy>Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: are you writing custom js for the burger menu hiding or are u using bootstrap and also can you make the problem much clear by explaining what you expect

Comment: Please explain the issue completely

Comment: I' m using bootsrap My espectation is that I want that the menu be hidden automatically when i click on it

Comment: How do you unhide it again? The js proposed as answer by @Rajesh will hide it for good - do you want this - hide it and never show it again? Please explain exactly what you think you want.

Comment: the js proposed by rajish just hide the icon i want to hide all the menu with its compsant (acceuil,services,competences contact) and i want it to appear only if i click on the icon

Comment: answer this if you hide everything how will you bring that back there is nothing left to click in the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".mob-menu").click(function(){ 
    $(this).hide(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Your code might vanish the burger menu - but I highly doubt that is what the q "really wants". Let her explain her expectations a bit, then you dont have to readjust your answers all the time to her changed expectations.

Comment: when I click on the icon of the burger menu the menu appear  (Acceuil competences services contact) then when i choose for exemple contact the menu still be opened and doesnt be hiden automatically so i cant see the body of my page because the menu hide it

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".mob-menu").click(function(){ 
    $("#myNavbar").toggle(); 
});

});


You can use this code to hide and show sidebar menu

Comment: thanks @Rajesh the problem  now is when i choose and click a link of a menu i want it to be hidden automatically without clicking on the icon

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/op5a1Lrr/    Please check here this might help you

Comment: this is exactly what I m searching about but it doesnt work in my code .

Comment: http://www.it-tecos.com/  this is the link of the website it is not the last version but maybe u can know where the problem is